# Tile Menu Component not displaying

Tags: navigation, menu

I have a community where I have created 3 custom tile navigation menus. When logged in, the menu shows but when I access the community as a public user the Tile Menu doesn't display. I have allowed Public access to the community and all other components used are displaying except the Tile Menu component. What I'm I missing or what is the issue? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I was able to figure this out. I was missing the "Read Access" to documents under the "Community User profile"
For those who may encounter the same, here are the correct settings for the "Tile Menu"

-Select Publicly available if you want the tile menu item to show for guest users that aren’t members of the community.

-Enable Let guest users view asset files on public and login pages in Workspaces | Administration. Then, give read access to Documents.

Comment: Giving the guest user profile read access to "Documents" was the thing I was missing.  Talk about unintuitive! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

To make the images in the tile menu viewable by guest site users:

- Enable Let guest users view asset files and CMS content available to the site in Administration | Preferences in Experience Builder.
- Access the site’s guest user profile and Object Settings.
  Then, give read access to Documents.

More [information here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.rss_tile_menu.htm&type=5)